# How can I make sure my Bearded Dragon's terrarium is safe after my apartment has been fumigated?

Tags: reptiles, poison, pest-control

I just received notice that my apartment is getting [bug-bombed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fogger) this weekend. I'm planning on moving my bearded dragon to a smaller terrarium so that it's easier to move him out for the day, but I don't want to bring him back at the end of the day and place him in his old terrarium that's been in the apartment while it was being bug-bombed.

I plan on putting some plastic over it. Is that enough to know that the tank is safe for me to put him in again? He licks things in his tank quite often, so I don't want him ingesting any of the poison. Would scrubbing the tank with soap and water be enough?

How do I make sure the tank is safe after the bug-bomb?

Comment: If i'm honest, i would try and get the main housing to a well ventilated area outside. If you can't do that, you'd have to REALLY clean it. Possibly with steam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was covering the terrarium in [plastic I found at Lowes](http://www.lowes.com/pd_16903-18632-RSBH210-100C_0__?productId=3224897). It seemed to be thick enough that it would block out the chemicals I thought. Once I wrapped it around the terrarium, I taped it all shut so that it was sealed off from anything getting inside.

I could tell it worked because the exterminator used too much spray, and there was a film of slime over everything. When I took the plastic off, the tank didn't have any of the slime, or smell even.

Still, to be safe, I cleaned the whole thing with Cold Life (I think it's only found in the Midwest US) which is a cleaning spray made for terrariums. It worked really well. I let the smell of the cleaning solution air out and put my bearded dragon back in and there have been no ill effects.